# Gulp: Produce several images from one image for multiple display automatically?

Tags: image, gulp, retina-display, srcset, gulp-imagemin

As title says, is there a way to do that in `gulp`? I need several images to be included in multiple `picture` or `img srcset` attributes. And this will be for asset on-the-site only (means, not user uploaded pictures).

I want to create 2 other images, one for tablet, one for mobile, using `gulp-copy`, but probably not recommended. I'm assuming mobile display will be between 320px-500px(width), and 500-1000px(width) for tablet.

My strategy is to optimize the image first, make that image as master, then generate 2 other images, so I **always** assume my source image will be for desktop (display width > 1000px). ***<-- if there is a task where i can pass paramaters for assuming it was other display, even better***

My other challenge is the `height` of the image, I do not have standards (and it's very hard to make one) for each display. So if I'm assuming 100px by 800px image is a **desktop** one, I don't know how to calculate it for mobile and tablet.

Is there anyone that have ever done this before? Resizing image resolution in gulp?

SOLVED: with `gulp-responsive-images`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be several gulp tasks which are able to do this.

Why don't you take a look at these:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-responsive

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-responsive-images

Comment: Well, forgot to flag my answer has been solved, thanks for the links anyway